# Resolving `CS102` Error: "unknown collection_id" in Crunchbase API `/searches/people` Endpoint

Tags: postman, swagger, httprequest

I've encountered a persistent issue when attempting to connect to the Crunchbase API using the /searches/people endpoint. Despite following the documentation and replacing the necessary parameters with valid sample values, I consistently receive an error with the code CS102, stating an "unknown collection_id". This occurs even when using the auto-generated cURL command from Swagger and when sending requests via Postman.

From my understanding, the collection_id typically refers to a specific set of data or a parameter that identifies a collection within an API endpoint. Since it is not explicitly mentioned in the Crunchbase API documentation for this endpoint, I'm unsure of its relevance or how to address this error.

Has anyone else faced this issue or can provide insight into what the collection_id pertains to in this context? Any guidance on how to resolve this error would be greatly appreciated.

[image]